# which JAXB implementation to use?

Tags: jaxb, apache-camel, moxy

I've been using the default Sun JAXB implementation that ships with the Oracle JDK 1.7.
Unfortunately I have certain quite complex XSD schemas to work with and I've hit what appears to be a bug in the XSD to Java engine (described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155414/jaxb-multiple-schemas-with-element-reference)).

It appears that only a workaround is possible and what's worse I haven't yet been able to apply the particular workaround in my individual case. What's more unsettling however is that a workaround should be required for what is in my view a very elementary case (one XSD schema referencing an element defined in another).

I know of at least two other JAXB implementations:

- [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/jaxb.html)
- [EclipseLink MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)

Would anyone have any insights into how these compare against each other and against Sun's JAXB ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

- **Apache Camel** - I believe Apache Camel just leverages JAXB and is not a JAXB
  (JSR-222) implementation itself.
- **EclipseLink MOXy** - There are many great reasons to switch to MOXy ([XPath based mapping](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html), e[xternal mapping metadata](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html), [JSON-binding](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html), etc).  But MOXy uses the XML Schema to Java Compiler (XJC) tool from the JAXB reference implementation so it won't fix this use case.

Comment: Correct Apache Camel just uses the JAXB API, eg the javax.xml.bind.annotation annotations. The default from the JDK is often buggy. You can download and use a newer version of JAXB, eg the JARs are in maven central.