# JAXBContext.newInstance variations

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I am experimenting with the various forms of **newInstance** method in class **JAXBContext** (I am using the default Sun JAXB implementation that ships with Oracle JDK 1.7).

It's not clear to me when it's ok to just pass to the **newInstance** method the concrete classes versus the **ObjectFactory** class. I should note that I am using JAXB purely for parsing XML files, i.e. only in the XML->Java direction.

Here's the absolutely minimal code that demonstrates my point:

### xsd file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns          ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:a        ="http://www.example.org/A"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/A">
    <element name="root" type="a:RootType"></element>

    <complexType name="RootType">
       <sequence>
           <element name="value" type="string"></element>
       </sequence>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

Given the above XSD, the following **JAXBInstance.newInstance** invocations succeed in creating a context that can parse a sample **a.xml** file:

- jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("example.a");
- jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(example.a.ObjectFactory.class);
- jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(example.a.RootType.class, example.a.ObjectFactory.class);

However, passing the **example.a.RootType.class** alone fails with **javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException** at runtime:

```
jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(example.a.RootType.class); // this fails at runtime.
```

Can anyone shed some light? The reason I am experimenting on these **JAXBContext::newInstance** variations is that I've stumbled on [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274482/jaxb-xsdinclude-and-separate-packages) where the accepted answer included the option of "building the JAXB context based on individual classes rather than object factories". The sample **a.xml** and the **JAXB** Java code I am using follow at the end of the post.

## sample a.xml used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a:root xmlns:a="http://www.example.org/A"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/A A.xsd">
    <a:value>foo</a:value>
</a:root>
```

## JAXB parsing code

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException {
    JAXBContext jc = null;
    message("using package context (press any key:)");
    jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("example.a");
    work(jc); // SUCCEEDS

    message("using Object factory (press any key):");
    jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(example.a.ObjectFactory.class);
    work(jc); // SUCCEEDS

    message("using class enumeration (press any key):");
    try {
        jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(example.a.RootType.class);
        work(jc);  // FAILS
    } catch (javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    message("using class enumeration and Object factory too (press any key):");
    jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(example.a.RootType.class, example.a.ObjectFactory.class);
    work(jc); // SUCCEEDS

}

private static void work(JAXBContext jc) throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException {
    Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    RootType root = ((JAXBElement<RootType>)u.unmarshal( new FileInputStream( "a.xml" ))).getValue();
    System.out.println( root.getValue() );
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**JAXB Model Generated from XML Schema**

When creating a `JAXBContext` from a model generated from an XML schema I always recommend doing it on the package name of the generated classes.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("example.a");
```

It is even better to use a `newInstance` method that  takes a `ClassLoader` parameter.  This will save you grief when you move from a Java SE to Java EE environment.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("example.a", example.a.ObjectFactory.class.getClassLoader());
```

When you create the `JAXBContext` on the package name, the JAXB impl assumes you generated the model from an XML schema and pulls in the `ObjectFactory` class since it always generates the class annotated with `@XmlRegistry` with this name.

**Starting from a Java Model**

This is when I recommend people use the `newInstance` methods that take classes.  When bootstrapping a `JAXBContext` from JAXB classes there is nothing special about a class called `ObjectFactory`.  The role of the `ObjectFactory` could be played by any class annotated with `@XmlRegistry` so it is not automatically looked for.  This is why your use case worked when you explictly reference `ObjectFactory` and failed when you did not.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I've been trying to fix a classloader problem for over a week and this trick is the only thing that's made everything work for me :)