# JAXB error while marshalling

Tags: jaxb, marshalling

I am getting this error when i am trying to marshal a JAXB object to XML. 
The JAXBContext is unable to find the class that i am passing. I am stuck up here.
Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getClassValue(RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.java:128)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getClassValue(RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.java:42)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.PropertyInfoImpl.isApplicable(PropertyInfoImpl.java:201)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.PropertyInfoImpl.getApplicableAdapter(PropertyInfoImpl.java:212)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.PropertyInfoImpl.<init>(PropertyInfoImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.SingleTypePropertyInfoImpl.<init>(SingleTypePropertyInfoImpl.java:60)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.AttributePropertyInfoImpl.<init>(AttributePropertyInfoImpl.java:48)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeAttributePropertyInfoImpl.<init>(RuntimeAttributePropertyInfoImpl.java:43)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.createAttributeProperty(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:144)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.addProperty(ClassInfoImpl.java:851)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.findFieldProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:387)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:290)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.getProperties(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:165)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:212)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:293)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.calcRef(TypeRefImpl.java:81)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.getTarget(TypeRefImpl.java:58)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:40)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:63)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:61)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:345)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:224)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:293)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.calcRef(TypeRefImpl.java:81)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.getTarget(TypeRefImpl.java:58)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:40)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:63)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:61)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:345)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:224)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:293)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:308)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:430)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:277)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1100)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:202)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:376)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:522)
    at src.example.MarshalCommlAuto.main(MarshalCommlAuto.java:48)
```

Comment: What type of environment are you running in (app server, Java SE, OSGi, etc)?  How are you creating your `JAXBContext`?

Comment: using JAVA SE, GlassFish.                                                                     This is how i am creating the JAXB Context. I also have the index file placed in the same directory. I am clueless of what i am doing wrong.    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CommlAutoPolicyInfoType.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(commlauto, file);
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(commlauto, System.out);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a `JAXBContext` from a Java class, the JAXB impl will also create metadata for all classes if can reach from it (including property types, super classes, and classes specified in annotations).  It will not package scan or pull in subclasses so care needs to be taken to ensure metadata is produced for all classes in your model.

If your model is generated from an XML schema then you should create the `JAXBContext` from the generated package name.  To ensure the classes are loaded correctly you should also specify the correct `ClassLoader`.   Assuming your package name is `com.example.foo` you can do the following.

```java
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.example.foo", CommlAutoPolicyInfoType.class.getClassLoader());
```

If your generate model spans multiple packages you separate the packages in context path using the `:` character.

```java
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.example.foo:com.example.bar", CommlAutoPolicyInfoType.class.getClassLoader());
```

**For More Information**

- [JAXBContext.newInstance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860759/jaxbcontext-newinstance-variations/16861006#16861006)

Comment: I tried that. It dint work though. I keep getting the same error. One thing that i tried was , giving another class name instead of the one that i need and it worked. All the JAXB objects were created from an XML schema, so my assumption is if one class can get picked up why not any other from the same package. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: @user2487308 - Specifying the package name should have worked for your use case (you need to specify the `ClassLoader` in an app server or OSGi environment.  I have updated my answer to provide some additional info.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem and this is was the problem with some transitive dependencies on the one of the big project within company (but I didn't get the ClassNotFound exception but that InternalError which points to nowhere). Even when I've used the hint suggested by @Blaise it didn't start work.

So - how I solve the problem? First - I've added the `-verbose:class` to command line in order to track down the loaded classes. With this I have figured out that some of the classes from my jaxb package (it could be that example package: `"com.example.foo"`) weren't loaded for some reason. So I've added example import for those non-loaded classes from jaxb package and simple usage on the code, like:

```
ExampleNotLoadedClass.class.getName();
```

With above code finally during loading this class I've received the `ClassNotFound` exception with the class from different package. It should be included by some transitive dependencies for this artifact but for some reason this didn't work (I think it doesn't matter, I would only say that we were dividing our big project and extracting some of the artifacts to different subprojects).

So I've added that missing class dependency directly to that problematic artifact and everything had started work fine.

I hope it helps someone in similar problem.