# Jaxb when use jaxb.index file

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I was investigating object `marshaling` and `unMarshaling` using `JAXB`. while noticed that there is two option of getting an instance of `JAXBContext`.

- one is based on class:  `JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ex.getClass());`
- Other one is based on package name: `JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ex.getClass().getPackage().getName());`

For the second way, you have to provide `jaxb.index` file, containing list of bean class names.

Maybe someone can explain, what is the difference between this two methods of getting `JAXBContext` instance? Which is better to use and when?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAXBContext.newInstance variations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860759/jaxbcontext-newinstance-variations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For the second way, you have to provide `jaxb.index` file, containing list of bean class names.

This is not correct. In JAXB2 this works without `jaxb.index` as well, the classes are "recognized" via `ObjectFactory` and `@XmlSeeAlso`.

The usual approach is to use `JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("my.package:my.another.package);` as you normally want to consider all of the relevant classes and don't want to enumerate them explicitly.

Comment: but still, what is the purpose of `jaxb.index`  and when create it?

Comment: @Bublik You can create it instead of the `ObjectFactory`. This might be more convenint if you write your JAXB classes by hand (vs. generating them from a schema).